# Not response and not error using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm working with cURL but i don't have any response and any error when I'm using it. I have looking for any answer on the web but i haven't found anything. Too appear "Resource id #478"

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ep);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=$json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$this->username:$this->password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$response = curl_exec($ch);     
curl_close($ch);
```

$json is an array and $ep is the url of the API with I'm working on.
When I use "echo $response", appear "Authorization Required"

So, the question is why don't I have any response and any error? Is the authentication maybe?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: What is the question exactly ??

Comment: Looks to me like authorization is required.

Comment: why don't i have any response and any error?

Comment: `Authorization Required` is the response...